# How to show the Netherlands time in hours (uur) in Dutch?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nsdatecomponents, nsdatecomponentsformatter

Show time for multiple countries with native time format.

Trying to Display time of Netherland eg: `22.37 uur`

**With Locale:** `nl_NL`

**For Date:** 2019-09-17 17:07:00 +0000

**I have tried the code below:**

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
var calendar = Calendar.gregorianCalendar()
calendar.locale = apiDate.locale // nl_NL
formatter.calendar = calendar
formatter.unitsStyle = .short
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = [.dropLeading, .pad]
let dateComponent = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: apiDate.absoluteDate) //apiDate.absoluteDate: Date : 2019-09-17 17:07:00 +0000
print(formatter.string(from: dateComponent) as Any) // prints 22 uur, 37 min
```

**Expected:** `22.37 uur`

**Actual:**  `22 uur, 37 min`

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you figure this out in the mean time?